# RequireJS shim custom jQuery plugin

Tags: requirejs

I have the following relevant code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3.min',       
        'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min',
            'customPlugin': 'customPlugin'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
            'customPlugin': {
                    deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
             }
        }
});
```

The problem is that RequireJS does not load jquery-ui for a module:

```
define(['customPlugin'], function...
```

When it's used. Please advice. It gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

That is, it doesn't find the jQueryUI datepicker plugin.

Comment: What happens or what fails to happen that indicates to you that it is not loading?

Comment: @Louis I added the error to my question now.

Comment: I see you are loading a custom build. Are you sure datepicker is in there? Otherwise, can we see the code that actually generates the error? And are you using RequireJS 2.1.11 or later?